# Why does 10>>2+5>>2 evaluate to zero?

Tags: java, operators

Consider the following code:

```
int a=10, b=5;
int c=a>>2+b>>2;
System.out.println(c);
```

When run, the (surprising) output is 0.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking Java's [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) (notably that `+` has higher precedence than `>>`) and associativity rules into account, the expression is equivalent to

```
(a >> (2 + b)) >> 2
```

or

```
(10 >> (2 + 5)) >> 2
```

which is zero.

If you need the shifts to happen before the addition, parenthesise them:

```
(a >> 2) + (b >> 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it's like writing [(Operator Precedence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

```
(a >> (2 + 5)) >> 2
```

Which is like writing:

```
(10 >> 7) >> 2
```

Which is 0. Why?

Think about the binary representation of 10, assuming 8-bit:

```
00001010
```

Now, shift it right by 7 and you'll get 0. Shift it right by 2, you'll still get 0.

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence!

If your code could be interpreted in a different way it almost certainly will one day. Always use brackets - never rely on operator precedence.

```
    int a = 10, b = 5;

    int c = a >> 2 + b >> 2;
    System.out.println(c);
    int d = (a >> 2) + (b >> 2);
    System.out.println(d);
    int e = ((a >> 2) + b) >> 2;
    System.out.println(e);
    int f = a >> (2 + b) >> 2;
    System.out.println(f);
```

prints

```
0
3
1
0
```